# How to map two list of list together to one value in my dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, mapping, maplist

I have two lists of lists that I am trying to map to another value in my dataframe.

Example of the list:

```
Potential_Cond_lst = [['Any Muscle Dis'], ['Type 2 fun','My happy place','Any Endo','Any Muscle Dis'],
 ['Mad people outiside','Ox tail','Hyper T','Wu Tang'],
 ['Type 2', 'Any Endo'],
 ['Other friends', 'Encounter for friends'],
 ['Any Endo', 'Any Muscle D', 'Major Frank'],
 ['Other friends', 'Any Muscle Disease'],.....]

Confidence_lvl_lst = [['50.8%'],
 ['96.3%', '94.1%', '94.0%', '61.5%'],
 ['99.0%', '99.0%', '93.6%', '45.5%'],
 ['99.0%', '89.4%'],
 ['70.0%', '31.5%'],
 ['92.6%', '70.7%', '20.0%'],
 ['88.1%', '59.2%'], ....]
```

I am trying to map these two list so they they would look like this:

```
Complete_lst = [['Any Muscle Dis': '50.8%'], 
['Type 2 fun': '96.3%','My happy place':'94.1%','Any Endo':'94.0%','Any Muscle Dis':'61.5%'], ['Mad people outiside': '99.0%','Ox tail':'99.0%','Hyper T':'93.6%','Wu Tang': '45.5%'], .....]
```

This way when I create a dataframe the output will look like this:

```
  
    ID              Reason                                                         Test Date of Reason                      Name of Test Done                            Potential Conditions with Confidence Level
0   87435   [Hanks Finger (11), Hanks left Finger (13), Hanks Right Finger (48]    2022-03-24                               [Hanks Finger (13), Hanks Left Finger (11)]  ([Any Muscle D: 50.8%])
1   49370   Franks and Beans (45)                                                  2022-07-05                               [Fransk and Beans (45)]                      ([Type 2 fun: 96.3%, My happy place:94.1% ,Any End: 94.0%, Any Muscle D: 61.5%])
```

Comment: Where ID comes from?

Comment: You can generate *list of dicts* using `list(map(dict, map(zip, Potential_Cond_lst, Confidence_lvl_lst))))` or `[dict(zip(*i)) for i in zip(Potential_Cond_lst, Confidence_lvl_lst)]`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. To be clear, this will create a list of *dictionaries* not a list of lists, although, based off what you have written, I'm not sure which one of those you want. For a list of lists, change `dict1 = {}` to `list1 = []`, `dict1[Potential_Cond_lst[i][n]] = Confidence_lvl_lst[i][n]` to `list1.append(Potential_Cond_lst[i][n]+':'+Confidence_lvl_lst[i][n])`, and `Complete_lst.append(dict1)` to `Complete_lst.append(list1)`.

```
Complete_lst = []
for i in range(0,len(Potential_Cond_lst)):
    dict1 = {}
    for n in range(0,len(Potential_Cond_lst[i])):
       dict1[Potential_Cond_lst[i][n]] = Confidence_lvl_lst[i][n]
    Complete_lst.append(dict1)
```

EDIT:
My original script did not perform the proper behavior, so I have edited it such that it now should. I would also like to note, just to be clear, that the syntax of your expected output is invalid; `['Any Muscle Dis': '50.8%']`, an example I took from the output that you wrote you are hoping for, will throw errors because values in lists are separated from each other with commas, not colons. The two closest syntaxes that I could think of for what you desire are a list of dictionaries (what the above code outputs) in the form `[{'key':'val'},{...}]` and a list of lists in the form `[['key : val'],[...]]`, which can be output by making the changes that I referenced above.

Comment: This gives [{'Any Muscle Disease': '50.8%'}, {'Any Muscle Disease': '61.5%'},
 {'Any Muscle Disease': '45.5%'}, {'Any Muscle Disease': '89.4%'}, ...] which is not what I was looking for, but appreciate the attempt.

Comment: Sorry, about that - I wrote my original script fairly hastily and did not notice the issue with it. Hopefully my edited answer will provide some clarity.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'zip' function and List Comprehension:

```
Complete_lst = [[k,v] for k,v in zip(Potential_Cond_lst, Confidence_lvl_lst)]

print(Complete_lst)
```

Output:

```
[[['Any Muscle Dis'], ['50.8%']], [['Type 2 fun', 'My happy place', 'Any Endo', 'Any Muscle Dis'], ['96.3%', '94.1%', '94.0%', '61.5%']], [['Mad people outiside', 'Ox tail', 'Hyper T', 'Wu Tang'], ['99.0%', '99.0%', '93.6%', '45.5%']], [['Type 2', 'Any Endo'], ['99.0%', '89.4%']], [['Other friends', 'Encounter for friends'], ['70.0%', '31.5%']], [['Any Endo', 'Any Muscle D', 'Major Frank'], ['92.6%', '70.7%', '20.0%']], [['Other friends', 'Any Muscle Disease'], ['88.1%', '59.2%']]]
```